# Javascript and Firebase - Create user with Email and password and onAuthStateChange

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication

Hi I'm having problems finding a way to have an auth state change auto direct to a page for logged in users. Before a user is created however I want to push to my database a user Profile.

So I create the user then add to the database with this code

```
firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).then(function (user){
  firebase.database().ref('/Profiles').child(user.uid).set({
    address: ''
  })
}).catch(function(error){
  let errorCode = error.code;
  let errorMessage = error.message;
  navigator.notification.alert('Error: Code: ' + errorCode + ', ' + errorMessage,false,'Error','Done');
});
```

However, Once the createUserWithEmailAndPassword is successful This onAuthStateChanged function navigates to the new page before the database 'Profile' record is added.

```
firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user) {
  if (user) {
    let u = firebase.auth().currentUser;
    window.location = 'loggedIn.html';

  }
});
```

How can I make it so that my onAuthStateChanged function waits for the database record to be added before navigating away from the page

NOTE:: I want to keep the onAuthStateChanged so that if a user is logged into the session they will auto directed to the loggedIn page

Answer (score 0):

You can try to register the onAuthStateChagned handler after saving to database.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I tried several stuffs but one simple setState for some reason solved this issue.

Try to setState for something inside the createUserWithEmailAndPassword function. For example:

```
firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).then(function (user){
  firebase.database().ref('/Profiles').child(user.uid).set({
    address: ''
  })
  // SET Some state
  this.setState({ error: null, isLoading: false });

  // Besides that I show the feedback as an alert (just in case you think it's a good idea)
  Alert.alert(
      `Welcome ${user.user.name}!`,
      'Your account has been successfully created.',
      [
        {
          text: 'OK',
          onPress: () =>
            navigation.navigate('Main'),
        },
      ]
    );

}).catch(function(error){
  let errorCode = error.code;
  let errorMessage = error.message;
  navigator.notification.alert('Error: Code: ' + errorCode + ', ' + errorMessage,false,'Error','Done');
});
```